# Is it possible to create an object from XML file using DOM?

Tags: java, dom, object, data-binding, xml-parsing

I use DOM parser to read data from XML file. I know how to read, modify and write back the data. However, I would like to know if it is possible to create an object from an XML file.

I have an XML file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE people SYSTEM "validator.dtd">

<people>
    <student>
        <name>John</name>
        <course>Computer Technology</course>
        <semester>6</semester>
        <scheme>E</scheme>
    </student>

    <student>
        <name>Foo</name>
        <course>Industrial Electronics</course>
        <semester>6</semester>
        <scheme>E</scheme>
    </student>
</people>
```

and I would like to make it an objects out of it so I can pass them around. Does a solution exist ?

Comment: The answer is yes ... but not with a DOM or a DOM parser.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at XML beans or JAXB libraries. In case you don't have a schema file but have a sample XML file, you could create one using inst2xsd tool of xmlbeans. http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/guide/tools.html. This could get you started with the schema.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is possible through JAXB (Java API for XML binding)

All JAXB implementations provide a tool called a binding compiler to bind a XML schema in order to generate the corresponding Java classes.

For details refer: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html#xmp1